# Problem adding deploy keys to github via API

Tags: github

I am following the guidelines published here: http://develop.github.com/p/repo.html

I am trying to add a public key to my set of deploy keys, using the GitHub API.

Creating the repo works fine:

```
curl -F "login=username" -F "token=ApiToken" https://github.com/api/v2/json/repos/create -F name=myrepo

{"repository":{"owner":"username","has_downloads":true,"forks":1,"url":"https://github.com/username/myrepo","watchers":1,"has_wiki":true,"fork":false,"size":0,"open_issues":0,"created_at":"2011/09/06 02:42:08 -0700","name":"myrepo","private":false,"has_issues":true}}
```

I can list the keys (emtpy for now):

```
curl -F "login=username" -F "token=ApiToken" https://github.com/api/v2/json/repos/keys/username/myrepo

{"public_keys":[]}
```

But I can not add keys (stays empty even after addition!):

```
curl -X POST -F "login=username" -F "token=ApiToken" https://github.com/api/v2/json/repos/key/username/myrepo/add -F "title=TheTitle" -F "key=ssh-rsa xxxxx..."

{"public_keys":[]}
```

Is there any limitation to the GitHub API, regarding key addition?

Comment: Did you tried with simple quotes instead of double quotes?

Comment: Yes, I did. I think the problem is that the key that I am trying to add is already assigned to another user, and github does not allow one key to be associated to several accounts. The error message in the user interface is more or less clear: `Oops! The key has already been taken.`, but the reply via API is silent.

Comment: did you try to add a bogus key, just to see if the api was working?

Comment: yes, I have. I have posted it below, in my answer. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem, so for reference here it is.
Github does not allow a public key to be associated to several users.
If you try to add the key using the web interface, you will get the following message:

```
Oops! The key has already been taken.
```

The API is silent. That is why I was confused.

Using a brand new key, the API works as expected and replies with:

```
curl -X POST -F "login=username" -F "token=ApiToken" https://github.com/api/v2/json/repos/key/username/myrepo/add -F "title=Bogus" -F "key=ssh-rsa xxxxx...."

{"public_keys":[{"title":"Bogus","id":1199679,"key":"ssh-rsa xxxx..."}]}
```

Comment: couldn't find anything in v3